# jQuery Mobile .click pass data variable

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have two buttons...

```
<a data-role="button" data-theme="g" href="#tops" class="track" data-track="tops"> Tops </a>
<a data-role="button" data-theme="g" href="#dresses" class="track" data-track="dresses"> Dresses</a>
```

When the href is loaded, e.g. #dresses there is an image:

```
<img class="item" src="images/dresses/item1.jpg")
```

I am trying to set up a JQuery function that will take the data-track value and assign it to a variable called trackSelection so I can have:

```
var locationString = "images/" + trackSelection + "/item1.jpg";
$('.item').attr('src', locationString)
```

This way the right image will be loaded when the button is selected. I've tried this and it didn't work:

```
 $(".track").click(function() {
      var trackSelection = $(this).data("track");
 });
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you've got. Can you describe why it didn't work.

Comment: `$('.item').attr('src', locationString)` This line will change source link of all the `.item` images.